# Find and print two blocks of lines from file with sed in one pass

Tags: sed

I am trying to come up with an sed command to find and print two blocks of variable number of lines from a text file that look like this:

```
...
INFO first block to match
id: "value"
...
last line of the first block
INFO next irrelevant block
id: "different value"
...
INFO second block to match
id: "value"
...
last line of the second block
...
```

I only have prior knowledge of the id value and the fact that each block starts with a line that has "INFO". I want to match each block from that first line and not include the first line of the next block in the output:

```
INFO first block to match
id: "value"
...
last line of the first block

INFO second block to match
id: "value"
...
last line of the second block
```

Ideally I would prefer to do it in a single pass, not have the file scanned multiple times from top to bottom. Currently I have this (it only matches the first block, and I need both):

`sed -n -e "/INFO/{"'$!'"{N;/INFO.*id: \"value\"/{:l;p;n;/^[^\\[]/bl;}}}" file.log`

### EDIT

Linebreak between blocks is certainly nice, but entirely optional.

### EDIT 2

Please note that `INFO` and `id: "value"` do not have to be in the beginning of the line, and all other words in my example are arbitrary and not known in advance. There can be any number of blocks (including 0) between and around the ones I need to match.

Comment: You mean you want to extract only the ID's? Please provide an example of the desired output, by editing the question.

Comment: [tag:awk] is a better tool for tasks like this. use sed for simple replacements and nothing else.

Comment: @oguz ismail what would the awk command for this be?

Comment: sth like this `awk '/^INFO/{p=0;a=$0;next} $0=="id: \"value\""{print a;p=1} p' file`

Comment: Your "EDIT 2" is essentially saying that the example you provided doesn't adequately cover your requirements. Fix the example so it does, otherwise we don't have something we can test a potential solution against to see if it works or not. You have multiple answers below and you're apologizing in the comments beneath all of them for issues with your example so again - just fix the example. Finally, sed is for doing s/old/new on individual strings - that's not what you're doing so you shouldn't be considering using sed for it.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is powerful, terse, and dumb. `awk` is smarter!

```
awk '/^INFO/{f = /match/? 1: 0} f'
```

*edit:* I see you want a linebreak between each "block"; will update if I find a tighter way:

```
awk '/^INFO/{f = /match/? 1: 0; if(i++) $0 = RS $0} f'
```

- `/^INFO/{action}`: Execute `{action}` only on lines beginning with "INFO"
- `variable = if ? then : else`: [Conditional Expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Conditional-Exp.html#Conditional-Exp) (ternary operator)
- `if(i++)`: The first time this is evaluated, `i` will be zero, thus the expression will be false. This prevents an extra line break at the first block.
- `$0 = RS $0`: Prepend a Record Separator (newline) to `$0` (entire record)
- `f` If f is greater than zero, `{print $0}` is implied.

Comment: This is impressively concise. Unfortunately, it does not work well in my case. Please see "EDIT 2" section in my question. Sorry if my example was misleading.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE ':a;/^INFO/{N;/^id: "value"/M!D;:b;H;$!{n;/^INFO/!bb};x;s/^/x/;/^x{2}/{s/^x*.//p;q};x;ba}' file
```

This solution stores the required blocks in the hold space, prefixed by a counter. Once the required number of blocks are stored the counters are removed, the blocks printed and the process quit.

The solution (based only on the input provided) supposes that an `id` (if it exists) always follows the the `INFO` line.

Comment: Wow, what a monstrosity! Oh man, and I foolishly thought I was somewhat comfortable around sed :D

Comment: This almost works, except that it outputs the line that follows the second block as well. I want to prevent it, especially because some of these blocks are followed by some kind of control character sequence that clears my terminal. Do you mind altering it to fix that, and also to allow INFO and id to be placed in an arbitrary position on the line?

Comment: Your command outputs a linebreak between blocks, which is great, but not strictly necessary, I put it in the example output by accident while editing the question from my phone, my bad.

Comment: @dols3m I have removed the empty line between blocks, but as to EDIT2?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution using a combination of `sed` and `awk`. It allows you to parse the input blockwise or recordwise. This approach relies on setting `awk` record separator (`RS`) to the empty string which makes awk read a full block in at a time.

So there are 2 steps:

1. Make the input record-parsable.
2. Process each record.

For your example this could something like this:

```
sed '1!s/^INFO/\n&/' infile | awk '/id: "value"/' RS= ORS='\n\n'
```

Output:

```
INFO first block to match
id: "value"
...
last line of the first block

INFO second block to match
id: "value"
...
last line of the second block
```

Comment: Do you mind updating it for the things I mentioned in my EDIT 2 section?

Comment: @dols3m: In what way? I apparently do not have a representative sample of the data. Please read and adhere to the [instructions](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of making your question MCVE compliant

Answer (score 0):

awk is good for this, and if you could set RS to a multi-character expression it would be ideal.  (gnu awk allows this, but why bother with gnu awk when there is perl?)

```
perl -wnle 'BEGIN{$/="INFO"; undef $\} print "$/$_" if m/id: \"value\"/' input
```

Basically, this sets the record separator (`$/`) to the string "INFO" (so now each of your "records" is a "line" to perl).  If the record matches the pattern `id: "value"`, it is printed with "INFO" prepended to the start.  (without `-n`, perl would retain the record separator the end of each record, which is not quite what you want).  By omitting the "undef $\", you can get an extra newline between records.  Some code golf could probably cut the length of this in half, but my perl is a bit rusty.  Waiting for the shorter version in comments.

Comment: Neat, but INFO might not be in the beginning of the line and I still want that line to be printed from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be what you want depending on what your real data looks like:

```
$ awk '/INFO/{info=$0; f=0} /id: "value"/{print info; f=1} f' file
INFO first block to match
id: "value"
...
last line of the first block
INFO second block to match
id: "value"
...
last line of the second block
```

or if you want to do more with each block than just print it as you go then some variation of this is better:

```
$ awk '
    /INFO/ { prt() }
    { block = block $0 ORS }
    END { prt() }
    function prt() {
        if (block ~ /id: "value"/) {
            printf "%s", block
        }
        block=""
    }
' file
INFO first block to match
id: "value"
...
last line of the first block
INFO second block to match
id: "value"
...
last line of the second block
```

The above will behave the same using any awk in any shell on any UNIX box.